# In which compilation unit lives a constexpr variable?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Consider this code:

```
struct foo
{
    static constexpr int value = 42;
};

void bar(const int* value) { std::cout << *value; }
int main() { bar(&foo::value); }
```

This compiles fine and without warnings under the [couple](https://ideone.com/i4bxrr) of [online compilers](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) I tried. Given that there is no single `.cpp` file defining the `constexpr` value, could the value of the pointer be different if the `bar` method is invoked from different compilation units? Or does the standard guarantee that the value ends up allocated only one time across all compilation units (ie an implicit `_declspec(selectany)`)?

Comment: Have you just compiled, or also linked the program?

Comment: As soon as you [actually use](http://ideone.com/Bi5oEt) the address, you need to provide a definition.

Comment: This code violates the one-definition rule, but since this is undefined behavior, compilers need not issue any warnings.

Comment: @cpplearner Where?

Comment: @KerrekSB, yup, this one works for example: https://ideone.com/i4bxrr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work for me---I get a linker error. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59e2cf56122733d0

If you do *not* odr-use the static constexpr member, you can imagine that it's inlined wherever required and doesn't live in any compilation unit. If you *do* odr-use it, as you have done in your program,  you *must* define it.

Comment: And how do you define it? I thought the value needed to be assigned at the declaration to be usable as constexpr. Do you assign it both at declaration and at definition?

Comment: @Trillian If you initialize it in the declaration, then you don't initialize it in the definition.

Comment: Yes but doesn't constexpr require initialization at declaration and odr initialization at definition?

Comment: @Trillian if you initialize the static member at declaration, you don't re-initialize it at definition. The copy of the variable that the linker actually emits a symbol for will be initialized during the initialization of non-local variables using the value from one of the declarations.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct but the situation will change in C++17, with the adoption of [inline variables (p0386)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r0.pdf). constexpr will then imply inline.

Comment: To be clear, only `constexpr` on a static class data member will imply inline :-)

Answer (score 1):

Generally taking the address of an object constitutes an odr-use, which would require the object to be defined somewhere (causing linker errors if it is not). However, address taking can be considered not an odr-use if the resultant expression is a discarded value. Arguably your use of it could be treated by some compilers as falling within the exemption as it is passed as parameter to a function which immediately discards it.